# Loop vs asynchronous timer

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, simulation

I am making a simulation where I need to run a day/night cycle. Here is the function that is in charge of the cycle:

```
def epoch():
    print("it is now day")
    time.sleep(varb.day_night_length)
    print("it is now night")
    time.sleep(varb.day_night_length)
```

(`varb` is the name of a global module I made and is a value that determines the length of the day or night)

The thing is I don't want this function to be the one in charge of when the program stops (making a for loop useless). I don't want it to be infinite so a while loop is cumbersome. I want to be able to run smoothly without stopping for user input. Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: I realized this loop is useless if I can't return the state of it. How can I do that without stopping the loop?

EDIT: found what I needed. For future people reading this, you have to use yield. It is used the exact same way as return just with the word yield.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Or multiple processes, or timed alarms. (I bluntly refuse to mark these up as `code` when they're not.)

Comment: I forgot to mention. I would also like to be able to "return" the state of epoch without breaking the flow.                               @tripleee how would timed alarms work? Is that part of python? Or a secondary program that I would need?

Comment: It's a U*x system call.  See [alarm(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) and https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: Ok secondary question. I need to be able to return the state of the cycle without interrupting the flow of the loop. How could I do this?P.S. will edit the original question to mention this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `threading`. It opens up a new thread separate from the rest of the code, meaning it won't stop the loop.

Try something on the lines of:

```
import time, threading
answer = ""
def user_input():
    answer = raw_input("Hello, how are you doing? ")
    global answer


Thread1 = threading.Thread(target = user_input)
for the_time in range(100): #Example loop
    time.sleep(2)
    print answer
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty proof of concept using Unix signals.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import signal
from time import sleep

NIGHT = 0

def toggle_night (foo, bar):
    global NIGHT
    NIGHT = 1 - NIGHT
    signal.alarm(2)

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, toggle_night)

signal.alarm(2)

events = ['The cows come home',
    'Time passes ...',
    'Birds chirp.',
    'Partially cloudy',
    'Cows? Where are they?',
    '... More time passes ...',
    'Here we are.']

for t, what in enumerate(events):
    print '{0} night: {1}: {2}'.format(t, NIGHT, what)
    sleep(1)
```

Demo:

```
tripleee@away:~$ python /tmp/night.py
0 night: 0: The cows come home
1 night: 0: Time passes ...
2 night: 1: Birds chirp.
3 night: 1: Partially cloudy
4 night: 0: Cows? Where are they?
5 night: 0: ... More time passes ...
6 night: 1: Here we are.
```

I tried the corresponding `setitimer` stuff as well but could not quickly get it to work... Anyway, all of this is U*x only.